# Show form validation errors on submit in angular template driven form

Tags: angular, angular5

I have created template driven form in Angular.

```
<form novalidate #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" #fullName="ngModel" required>
<div *ngIf="fullName.errors?.required && fullName.touched" class="validation-message">Required</div>
<button type="submit">Post</button>
```

It shows error when it is invalid and touched. I need to display error when form is submitted i.e. when the submit button is clicked.

```
onSubmit({value, valid}): void {
    if (valid) {
      console.log(value);
    } else {
      console.log('invalid form');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In **onSubmit** method iterate through all form controls and simply mark them as touched

```
Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
  form.controls[key].markAsTouched();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to be true when it's valid and use $ngIf:
HTML

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="fullname"          name="fullname" #input="ngModel">
        <div style="color:red" *ngIf="submittedError">
                Error
        </div>
        <br><br>
    <button type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Typescript:

```
submittedError;
...  
onSubmit({value, valid}): void {
    if (valid) {
     this.submittedError=false;
      console.log(value);
    } else {
     this.submittedError=true;
      console.log('invalid form');
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-96wlsf)

Comment: Yes, I know this but if there are multiple form fields to be validated, then how to target the error displaying div of the respective erroneous form field?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an extra flag to do that.

Like below,

```
submitted = false;
onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
```

And insert `submitted` into `*ngIf` statement.

Reference :
https://angular.io/guide/forms#toggle-two-form-regions-extra-credit

Comment: Yes, I know this but if there are multiple form fields to be validated, then how to target the error displaying div of the respective erroneous form field?

Comment: I think that question is totally different with the question which you wrote first. I think your code is already enough to show error for each forms. Each **formcontrol** returns **formcontrol.error** only if it is invalid. If a **formcontrol** is valid, **formcontrol.error** is **undefined**. Frankly, I do not use your code pattern but use the pattern like `formControlName="fullName"` and addtional `form.ts` file. So, I cannot guarantee you that the specific code works or not. But, on **formcontrol** points, it is right. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#errors

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers: ngForm has a submitted flag exposed. So, just create a template variable, and do a ngIf on the errors (ie. ngForm.submitted === true)